# Get current time zone id in Go

Tags: datetime, go

I have an abbriviation of the current time zone. And I want to have its full representation. Say, I have MSK. How to get "Europe/Moscow", which is the result of "cat /etc/timezone" in Ubuntu? Googled a lot, tried many examples, but didn't find...

Comment: There is nothing in the standard library that converts abbreviations because they are ambiguous. To read /etc/timezones use [ioutil.ReadFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile)

Comment: Why ambiguos? MSK stands only for "Moscow", isn't it?

Comment: What about non-linux way? Where should I get it in Windows? Registry?

Comment: `MSK` may by unique, but many are not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations.

Comment: Yes, `IST` for example may stand for India Standard Time, Irish Standard Time or Israel Standard Time.

Comment: OK, how can I get this full representation anyway, without the abbriviation, using Go? The place, where the program runs is not ambiguous...

Answer (score -2):

As Peter stated, there's nothing in the standard library for this, but if you *know* your app is always going to be running on linux you could use [os.Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/)

eg:

```
tz := "MSK"
out, err := exec.Command("grep", tz, "/etc/timezone").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("The %s timezone is %s\n", tz, out)
```

Comment: The code you've written is wrong. If the fixes are made, then it'll run fine, but it's not generic as well. First no `err` is there and `exec.Command(...).Output()` returns `([]byte, error)`, so it should be `out, err := exec.Command("grep", tz, "/etc/timezone").Output()`.

Also, `/etc/timezone` is applicable for Debian based OS.

Plus, import `fmt`

@denn, take note!

Comment: Why shell out to grep when you can simply read the file directly, and aren't using any options specific to grep?

Comment: @Subham, yes, I took it as a template.

Comment: @Subham thanks for spotting the error in my code.  fixed

Comment: @JimB I was simply offering an alternative to reading the file and searching through it.  the presence of /etc/timezone is not only OS specific, it's also distro specific, so no solution involving searching through it is a good solution.  that said, if you're going to search through a file for some text, why reinvent the wheel?